Angular Interceptor - re-execute the same HTTP Interceptor after a catch
I'm looking for a solution to re-execute the same HTTP query after a catch is completed.
For instance, as per below, I would like to re-execute the same call as the catch hanlded properly the re-authentication.
See below:
import { HttpContextToken, type HttpRequest, type HttpInterceptorFn, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';


export const REFRESHER_TOKEN_INTERCEPTOR = new HttpContextToken(() => false)
export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req: HttpRequest<any>, next) => {

  const authService = inject(AuthService)
  const operationName = req.body.operationName.toLowerCase();
  const isRefresherToken = operationName.toLowerCase() === 'refreshtoken' ? true : false
  //By dafault, the interceptor will try to pass the JWT token but for the refresherToken we must pass the refresher token instead
  const jwtToken = authService.getToken(isRefresherToken)
  console.log(`JWTToken:${jwtToken}`)
  if (jwtToken) {
    const cloned = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
      }
    })
    return next(cloned).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
          switch (err.status) {
            case 401:
              authService.refreshToken()
              //I WOULD LIKE TO REEXECUTE THE SAME CALL HERE AS THE USER IS SUPPOSED TO BE IDENTIFIED AGAIN
              break;
          }
        return throwError(() => err)
      })
    )
  }
  return next(req);
};


Make sure your authService.refreshToken() returns an observable, then we can use switchMap to switch to the original calling API. Also we return this observable instead of just executing it, so that the subscribe happens and the logic is executed.
return next(cloned).pipe(
  catchError((err: any) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
      switch (err.status) {
        case 401:
          return authService.refreshToken().pipe(     // <- changed here!
            switchMap(() => next(req))                // <- changed here!
          );                                          // <- changed here!
      }
    return throwError(() => err)
  })
)


I think we should modify the next(req). Because req still contains the old token.

it should be like,
switchMap((response) => {const newcloned = req.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: Bearer ${response['token']}}})return next(newcloned);})
